# Is there a way to write in an locale database?

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi, firemonkey

i'm learning to use firemonkey, and i made an app that i'm using on my phone (it works like a reminder if u want) so basically there's a database file (SQLite) in my phone's internal storage, and in the form i put a TMemo + FDConnection + FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink so the app can read the database and display it on the TMemo, now i did put a TEdit and i added a button i want what i write on the TEdit to be added to the database.
i'm new to SQL delphi and stack overflow in general.
thanks

PS: i'm trying to do it without using livebindings.

```
var
  query: TFDQuery;
begin

  query := TFDQuery.Create(nil);

  try
    // Define the SQL Query
    query.Connection := FDConnection1;
    query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Employee';
    query.Open();
    outputMemo.Text := '';
    // Add the field names from the table.
    outputMemo.Lines.Add(String.Format('|%8s|%-25s|%-25s|', [' ID ', ' NAME >',
      ' DEPARTMENT ']));
    // Add one line to the memo for each record in the table.
    while not query.Eof do
    begin
      outputMemo.Lines.Add(String.Format('|%8d|%-25s|%-25s|',
        [query.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger, >query.FieldByName('Name').AsString,
        query.FieldByName('Department').AsString]));
      query.Next;
    end;

  finally
    query.Close;
    query.DisposeOf;
  end;

end;
```

this is the code to display the database, i want to know if there's a way to write on the memo or a TEdit and press a button to change back the database, i'm wondering if it works both ways.

Comment: You should read up on Delphi's [Live Bindings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/LiveBindings_in_RAD_Studio), which is a complete framework for displaying and editing database records using GUI controls like TEdit, TMemo, TStringGrid, etc.  But it is a large topic ...

Comment: yeah i know thanks for answering, sorry i forgot to specify it i don't want to use livebindings, that's why i'm struggling so much.

Comment: @MartynA Personally I avoid things such as live bindings or db aware controls. They all work in the context of the main thread, blocking it. I *always* put communication in a background thread to keep the UI responsive - especially important on Android (which completely terminates your app if it doesn't respond in a short time). A multi-threaded multi-tiered event-driven design is the way to go, at least for me.

Comment: @MartynA The way I see it, there are two ways to go: fast development (RAD), or robust and scalable code. You very seldom get both. But for someone who's new to Delphi and SQL, perhaps it is a good starting point. But it's an introduction to very poor practice.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Well, I certainly agree that the thoughtless (and very often clueless) use of a tool because it produces instant results (for the developer, I mean) has a lot to answer for.  The worst examples, ime, aren't TBEdit and its ilk, but the client-side report generators.  Usually applied without any apparent thought as to multi-user issues.

Comment: @PauloHaddad Addressing your question, yes, of course there's a way. You're already reading from the fields the same way you need to for an edit control, such as `query.FieldByName('Name').AsString`. Just read that and assign it to the edit's `Text` property. Then to save, enter the query's `Edit` mode, assign the text to the query the same way `query.FieldByName('Name').AsString := SomeEdit.Text;` and then `Post` the query to save it. You should do some more research of your own on Delphi's database components.

Comment: It sounds like you need a tutorial.  I would suggest starting by reading through the documentation for SQLite.  [How to insert data](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/), for example, [or how to update data](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-update/).

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/FireDAC